# List of fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know that to show a list of views I can use recycler view with but what if I wanna reuse also my fragment logic too?

for example, if I have a fragment like this

***XML***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.fragments.testview">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="hi"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Fragment class***

```
public class TestView extends Fragment {
    private TextView txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
        initComponent(v);

        return v;
    }

    private void hardTask1(){};
    private void hardTask2(){};
    //Some other hardtask
}
```

What I could do if I need to display a list of fragments in some activity but I don't want to rewrite all my TestView in the adapter?

Comment: put TestViewFragment() in List

Comment: Sorry @GuanHongHuang but i don't really get what you mean, should I use a recycler view with a List<TestView>?

Comment: put TestViewFragment() in List so you can show fragment by
`FragmentManager.show(FragmentList.get(index))`